# Is there a correlation between a vegan diet low in Vitamin B12 and the occurrence or severity of vitiligo?

Tags: dermatology, micronutrients, vitiligo, vitamin-b, malnutrition

Studies have shown a significant reduction of Vitamin B12 levels in individuals with vitiligo. This meta-analysis provides an overview: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30165163/

> **Results**: Twenty-two studies involving a total of 1448 patients with
> vitiligo were included. Patients with vitiligo had significantly
> higher serum homocysteine levels (standardized mean difference [SMD]
> 0.550, 95% confidence interval [CI] 0.262-0.838; I2 87.3%) and lower vitamin B12 levels (SMD -0.430, 95% CI -0.738 to -0.121; I2 85.3%)
> than controls. Serum folate levels were not significantly different
> between the 2 groups (SMD -0.240, 95% CI -0.592 to 0.111; I2 85.5%). A
> subgroup analysis revealed that these findings correlated with disease
> activity.

Given that Vitamin B12 is primarily found in animal-based foods such as meat, poultry, fish, eggs, and dairy, I was curious if there is a relationship between a vegan diet and the prevalence or progression of vitiligo.

Comment: I am in no position to answer your question, but I have referred it to my sister who has vitiligo.  I am looking into the link between Vitamin B12 deficiency and how the symptoms can sometimes be misdiagnosed as dementia with devastating consequences.